# Generating SHA256 in Swift (iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, swift, sha256, hmac

I am trying to generate SHA256 using the following function:-

```
 func generateHMAC(key: String, data: String) -> String {
    let keyData = key.dataFromHexadecimalString()! as NSData
    let dataIn = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)
    var result: [CUnsignedChar]
    result = Array(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), keyData.bytes, keyData.length, dataIn!.bytes, dataIn!.length, &result)

    let hash = NSMutableString()
    for val in result {
        hash.appendFormat("%02hhx", val)
    }

    return hash as String
}
```

Input is

```
AccountNumber: 100195
Amount: 10 
BillerID: 59 
ChannelID: 2 
Context: 11|test
CountryID: 1 
CustomerID: 34
EmailID: ankur.arya@me.com
ReturnURL: https://uat.myfatoora.com/ReceiptPOC.aspx 
SECURITYTOKEN: 6B4A47A6-40A0-4C9D-A925-5CECA2910881 
TxnRefNum: 991107844408242 
UserName: USP
```

and the output is

```
4cd1acc736a9702c8cdb1a546d1c274a67cb285dbdbb972aab39ee51c2a2‌​26c8
```

However, this doesn’t match with the output of backend which uses the following algo

```
private string CreateSHA256POC(bool useRequest)
    {
        // Hex Decode the Secure Secret for use in using the HMACSHA256 hasher
        // hex decoding eliminates this source of error as it is independent of the character encoding
        // hex decoding is precise in converting to a byte array and is the preferred form for representing binary values as hex strings. 
        secureHash = "";
        byte[] convertedHash = new byte[_secureSecret.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < _secureSecret.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            convertedHash[i] = (byte)Int32.Parse(_secureSecret.Substring(i * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        }

        // Build string from collection in preperation to be hashed
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        SortedList<String, String> list = (useRequest ? requestFields : responseFields);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in list)
        {
            // if (kvp.Key.StartsWith("vpc_") || kvp.Key.StartsWith("user_"))
            sb.Append(kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value + "&");
        }
        // remove trailing & from string
        if (sb.Length > 0)
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

        // Create secureHash on string
        string hexHash = "";
        using (HMACSHA256 hasher = new HMACSHA256(convertedHash))
        {
            byte[] hashValue = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));
            foreach (byte b in hashValue)
            {
                hexHash += b.ToString("X2");
                secureHash = hexHash;
            }
        }
        return hexHash;
    }
```

and their output is

```
41D8E81C128100A76185F24CE00BC6A4FEA30839E6DE3DFFBC3B5814E4FD0C4E
```

Secret key is

```
71DD0F73AFFBB47825FF9864DDE95F3B
```

Can you please help me to update my method in Swift to get the same result as backend.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not very experience with C#, but doesn't `SortedList` *sort* he key/value pairs using the key? That would be a different order as in your Swift code. – Also it seems that you convert the string to UTF-8 data in C#, but to UTF-16 data in Swift. – You should compare all intermediate results in order to find the problem.

Comment: Also without knowing the key/secureSecret nobody can verify your results.

Comment: Hey @MartinR Thanks for your reply. Keys should be sorted. and below is the key. "71DD0F73AFFBB47825FF9864DDE95F3B"" Updated in question too.

Comment: With that key and the given input I get `4cd1acc736a9702c8cdb1a546d1c274a67cb285dbdbb972aab39ee51c2a226c8` as the hash. Can you post complete self-contained Swift code with input and output and the `dataFromHexadecimalString` method?

Comment: Hey,  I have already added the Input and output. Can you please tell which is the code you are talking about?

Comment: I have called `let hmac = generateHMAC(key, data: requestString)` where `let key = "71DD0F73AFFBB47825FF9864DDE95F3B"` and `let requestString = "AccountNumber=100195..."` is your input. The result is as in my previous comment. – Actually your Swift code produces the hash as *lowercase* hex numbers, so the output *cannot* be `A765D2EE70B991F289C7EE76210CD40966F8EDBA0550AD1E2B3752AC0A6AAF1B` as you claimed.

Comment: Case doesn't matter. @MartinR Thanks for helping. Btw I am looking for the code that produce hash that matches with Backend

Comment: Your Swift code does not produce the result that you claimed. Can we be sure that your C# code produces the claimed result?  – Without *reproducible* examples we can only guess about the problem.

Comment: I checked it again and I got the same out as yours but I am certain about the c# result. How can we make it like them?

Comment: I tested you C# code and could not get the same result as your _their output_ -- `41D8E81C...E4FD0C4E`. Your C# code needs a `SortedList` in `requestFields` (or in `responseFields`), not a single string. What was your actual _input_ when you get `41D8E81C...E4FD0C4E`?

Comment: @OOPer updated question. Please check and share your feedback

Comment: All the same. Your updated _Input_ does not generate the _output_ with your C# code and the _Secret key_. I really doubt if you actually run your C# code and got the _output_ by yourself. Please come again when you are ready for providing the issue-reproducible input, output and code.